# Receiving UDP packet in swift

Tags: swift, udp

I am trying to receive a udp packet from a caller id interface but am unable to do so. I am using the following code to listen but not getting any data

The link for the call tester application is here
http://callerid.com/files/3014/5772/4362/eed-1-4.msi

```
class InSocket: NSObject, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {
    let IP = "255.255.255.255"
    let PORT:UInt16 = 3520

    var socket:GCDAsyncUdpSocket!

    override init(){
        super.init()
        setupConnection()
    }

    func setupConnection(){
        let error : NSError?
        socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        do {
            try socket.connectToHost(IP, onPort: PORT)
            try socket.beginReceiving()
        }catch let cError as NSCocoaError{
            print(cError)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromAddress address: NSData, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject?) {
        print("incoming message: \(data)");
    }
}
```